# pandas DataFrame: match a dataframe and a dict by intervals

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, intervals

I have a question concerning DataFrames. I have a Dataframe, with intervals of 0.1 sec and features belong to that interval. I want to add a column that contains the prediction (is this interval a silence or a sounding) from a previous algorithm. I have a dictionary containing all predicted silence intervals per audio recording. My Dataframe will look like this. Here the df is filtered on audio_id==0 and ordered on interval_x.

```
 audio_id interval_x    interval_y  predicted_value
0   0   0.579367    0.679367    0
1   0   0.679367    0.779367    0
2   0   0.779367    0.879367    0
3   0   0.879367    0.979367    0
4   0   0.979367    1.079367    0
... ... ... ... ...
518 0   50.805830   50.905830   0
519 0   50.905830   51.005830   0
520 0   51.005830   51.105830   0
521 0   51.105830   51.205830   0
522 0   51.205830   51.212938   0
```

My dictionary containing the silence intervals looks like this:

```
{'0': [[1.4501383219954658, 2.058138321995466],
 [3.298138321995466, 4.762138321995465],
 [7.682138321995467, 8.266138321995465],
 [11.266138321995466, 11.938138321995465],
 [13.242138321995466, 13.706138321995466],
 [16.73013832199547, 17.82613832199547],
 [24.53813832199547, 25.130138321995467],
 [26.394138321995467, 27.042138321995466],
 [28.21013832199547, 28.722138321995466]],

'1': [[0.0, 0.31253968253968023],
 [4.296539682539681, 5.040539682539681],
 [8.64053968253968, 9.296539682539679],
```

etc for each audiofile.

What is an efficient way to do this?

Comment: Could you please provide a piece of expected output? If I read this correctly, all the intervals between time 1.45 and 2.05 should be set to '1', because the dictionary states that something happened during this timeframe. Correct?

Comment: Expected output would be the column predicted value, I now added a example column with 1's for silences and 0's for sounds. And yes you read it correctly, but the intervals are not all shown because I ordered the df on audio_id, and not on interval_x, so the intervals are mixed up. Should I give you a piece of ordered on interval?

Comment: It would be great if you could provide a small example of both the data frame and the dictionary, that demonstrates what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Allright, thanks in advance! The dict I already gave a small example, keys are the audio_id, and the values are a list of silence intervals. In my dataframe, the audio recordings are cut in 0.1 s, what I want is that all 0.1 s fragments belonging to one of the silence intervals get a 1 as predicted value.

Comment: So ... to make sure I get it: te predicted value should be 1 if there's an interval in the dictionary which includes the interval in the data frame?

Comment: Exactly! I am a bit stuck how to do this in a good manner.

Comment: Do you think you can help me? @Roy2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution, using `merge_asof` to match intervals to their closest silent times. `d` is the dictionary from the question, and `intervals` is the data frame.

```
silent_times = pd.DataFrame.from_records([(file, from_time, to_time) for file, values in d.items() 
                                          for [from_time, to_time] in values], 
                         columns = ["audio_id", "from_time", "to_time"])
silent_times.audio_id = silent_times.audio_id.astype(int)
res = pd.DataFrame()
for inx in intervals.audio_id.unique():
    intervals_slice = intervals[intervals.audio_id == inx]
    silent_times_slice = silent_times[silent_times.audio_id == inx]
    t = pd.merge_asof(intervals_slice, silent_times_slice, left_on=["interval_x"], right_on=["from_time"])   
    t.loc[(t.interval_x>=t.from_time) & (t.interval_y <=t.to_time), "predicted_value"] = 1
    res = res.append(t)
```

The result for the dataframe from the question, and for this silent intervals:

```
d = {'0': [
 [1.4501383219954658, 2.058138321995466],
 [3.298138321995466, 4.762138321995465],
 [7.682138321995467, 8.266138321995465],
 [50.01, 51.01]           
 ],
 '1': [
 [0.0, 0.31253968253968023],
 [4.296539682539681, 5.040539682539681],
 [8.64053968253968, 9.296539682539679]]}
```

Is as follows:

```
print(res[["audio_id_x", "interval_x", "interval_y", "predicted_value"]])
   audio_id_x  interval_x  interval_y  predicted_value
0           0    0.579367    0.679367                0
1           0    0.679367    0.779367                0
2           0    0.779367    0.879367                0
3           0    0.879367    0.979367                0
4           0    0.979367    1.079367                0
5           0   50.805830   50.905830                1
6           0   50.905830   51.005830                1
7           0   51.005830   51.105830                0
8           0   51.105830   51.205830                0
9           0   51.205830   51.212938                0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! One thing I am trying to change is that the intervals from the dataframe are also predicted as 1 when they overlap with the silence interval from the dict, not only when they are between x and y. I am talking about this line:
t.loc[(t.interval_x>=t.from_time) & (t.interval_y <=t.to_time), "predicted_value"] = 1

 I tried it like this:  t.loc[max(t.interval_x, t.from_time)<=min(t.interval_y, t.to_time), "predicted_value"] = 1
But I keep getting the following error: 
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Let me look at that.

Comment: The line you're looking for is: t.loc[ t[["interval_x", "from_time"]].max(axis="columns") <= t[["interval_y", "to_time"]].min(axis="columns"), "predicted_value"] = 1. But - I don't know if it's enough to identify all overlaps, because the way my join_asof works is that is' looking for an interval that starts *after* the silent time. To look for overlaps in the other direction you'll have to run another 'join_asof' in which you're looking for silent times that start just *after* the interval starts.

Comment: `t = pd.merge_asof(df, silent_times_slice, left_on=["interval_x"], right_on=["from_time"])`
`t.loc[t[["interval_x", "from_time"]].max(axis="columns") <= t[["interval_y", "to_time"]].min(axis="columns"), "predicted_value"] = 1`
`t = pd.merge_asof(silent_times_slice, df, left_on=["interval_x"], right_on=["from_time"])`
`t.loc[t[["interval_x", "from_time"]].max(axis="columns") <= t[["interval_y","to_time"]].min(axis="columns"), "predicted_value"] = 1`
This gives me a Keyerror on from_time

Comment: How can you do two join_asof functions parallel?

Comment: What you'll have to do it run two merge_asof operations (sorry - not join_asof). The one I provided looks at the start time of the interval, and looks 'backward' for the silent time which is closest to this interval. You'll have to create another dataframe that looks forward from the end time of each interval. You can do that with direction='forward' in a merge_asof operation. Then, you'll have to join the two dataframes using regular merge.